# Multiple tags for IDLE on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed that two tags exist for the Python IDE IDLE on Stack Overflow, [idle](/questions/tagged/idle) and [python-idle](/questions/tagged/python-idle). They should most likely be merged, considering that they cover the same topic.

Comment: I think this shouldn't even be a synonym. We should burninate `idle` and be done with it.

Comment: But there are more questions under `idle` than there are under `python-idle`. I guess I'll work on merging the tag wikis.

Comment: I cleaned up the tag wiki for `python-idle`, pending edit review.

Comment: And the tag wiki has been updated! I still think we should make `idle` a synonym, though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please someone create a tag synonym.

[python-idle](/questions/tagged/python-idle) should be the main tag (more specific) and [idle](/questions/tagged/idle) should be a synonym. I'd do this myself but haven't yet accumulated enough upvotes on the tags.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that we should keep `python-idle` as the main tag, makes the most since here.

Comment: I'll put it to the Python chat room; surprisingly, with 11k upvotes on the `python` tag I have none for `python-idle`.

Comment: Actually, I can do it all. Done. Woah - power rush to the head. Need to sit down.

Comment: @Oded if you find yourself in need another power kick, you can add the [meta-tag:status-completed] tag to this question.