# Another tag merger regarding IDLE

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Even after [this merger request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175206/191285) I have found yet another tag duplicate for Python's IDLE IDE in the form of [idle-ide](/questions/tagged/idle-ide). It currently has only 48 questions attached to it, a quick search shows that many are cross tagged to [python-idle](/questions/tagged/python-idle), which was determined as the main tag in the previous discussion. Can we get a merger here?

Comment: You should retag them yourself if there's only 48 questions.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII OP doesn't have enough rep.

Comment: "only 48 questions" - how many would merit help then?

Comment: When doing more than a handful, it's always best to do a sanity check on Meta, just in case someone has a better idea.  Personally I think `idle-ide` is a heck of a lot more clear than `python-idle` as a tag name, but whatevs.

Comment: What should I do then? Should I retag myself?